# Set input text-field "expiration date" one year after "effective date"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input text-fields, an "effective date" and an "expiration date."  I'm using jquerytool's dateinput function as the date-picker.

Question:
When the "effective date" is picked, I'd like the "expiration date" to be one-year from the "effective date" and to set that value to the "expiration date" text-input field.

I cannot seem to get this all working...

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(":date").dateinput({
    format: 'mmmm dd, yyyy', // the format for example: 'October 04, 2012'
  });

function expiration (){
  // date calculations here?...
  ...
  document.getElementById('expiration').value = expirationDate;

}
</script>


<input type="date" name="effective" id="effective" onChange="expiration()" />

<input type="date" name="expiration" id="expiration" />
```

Comment: What's not working?  Is the error in the date calculations, or in passing them to the HTML?  What happens if inside expiration() you hard code expirationDate to something?

Comment: @DanPichelman - I'm going to try and hard code expirationDate now.  I've gotten a few general errors of the code not working (bad js syntax) and also NaN errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

function expiration (){
  // date calculations here...
  var effectiveDate = document.getElementById('effective').value;

  var expirationDate = new Date(effectiveDate);

  expirationDate.setDate(expirationDate.getDate()+365);

  document.getElementById('expiration').value = expirationDate;

}
</script>
```